# php Laravel- retrieve property of object

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like that :

In my controller , I wrote this line :

```
dd($file->path);
```

and here is result :

```
UploadedFile {#294
  -test: false
  -originalName: "photo.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -size: 319216
  -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"
  basename: "phpLJA6Ge"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpLJA6Ge"
}
```

I want to return *.png* . How to retrieve *originalName*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of the file with extension included: `$file->getClientOriginalName()`

To get the content: `file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());`

Comment: Thank you for your comment . If file name is something like this.is.file.png , how to retrieve "png"? 

I use  explode('.',$file->getClientOriginalName()) but it return "this"

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If you explode on the `.`, it will return an array of multiple strings (because you have multiple dots in the file name). To get an extension, you always have to get the last in the array: `end(explode('.',$file->getClientOriginalName()))`.